Download qr code styling from safrai, the qr logo is missing
Use qr code styling(https://qr-code-styling.com/),I download qr(PNG format) from safari and the logo is missing, but its fine for chrome or download svg format by safari
const downloadQRCode = new QRCodeStyling({
            width: downloadSize,
            height: downloadSize,
            data: props.data,
            image: props.imageUrl,
            type: "png", // or "canvas"
            data: props.data,
            image: props.imageUrl,
            imageOptions: { "hideBackgroundDots": false, "imageSize": 0.3, "margin": 0 },
            qrOptions: { "mode": "Byte", "errorCorrectionLevel": "H" },
            backgroundOptions: {
                color: "#ffffff",
            },
            dotsOptions: props.dotsOptions,
            cornersSquareOptions: props.cornersSquareOptions,
            cornersDotOptions: props.cornersDotOptions
        });


        await downloadQRCode.download({
            name: 'qr',
            extension: downloadFormat.toLowerCase()
        });

I try to del 「type: "png"」,but problem is still here
